# Deserialising JSON files in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I keep getting following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

This is my Json string in a file at C:\part_param.json

```
{    
    "part_parameters" : {
        "bar_diameter" : 300.4,
        "core_height" : 132,
       "roughing_offset" : 0.3    
    } 
}
```

and the code I am using is as follows:

```
    public class PLMpartParameter
    {
        public class Parameters
        {
            public float bar_diameter;
            public float core_height;
            public float roughing_offset;

            public Parameters(float barD, float coreH, float roughingO)
            {
                bar_diameter = barD;
                core_height = coreH;
                roughing_offset = roughingO;
            }
        }
        public Parameters parameters;

        public PLMpartParameter(Parameters param)
        {
            parameters = param;
        }

    }


    public static void LoadJson()
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader r = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\part_param.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            _logger.Info(string.Format("Read entire file complete. File Values: {0}", json));

            try
            {
                PLMpartParameter part = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PLMpartParameter>(json);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Info(string.Format("Read Json failed {0}", e.Message));
            }
        }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: the line throwing the exception may be ? are you sure _logger is set ?

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You have a field called `parameters`, but your JSON has a property called `part_parameters`. (I'd personally urge you to make the `Parameters` class top-level, and use properties instead of public fields, with `[JsonProperty]` to specify the name in the JSON file so you can keep the code compliant with .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: As @JonSkeet is here, I deleted my answer. ;)

Comment: This line throws error

PLMpartParameter part = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PLMpartParameter>(json);

Comment: Also once you fix that, the JSON will not deserislise because the JSON structure doesn't match the class structure. I'm thinking particularly of "part_parameters" in the JSON vs "public Parameters parameters" in the C# - the property names need to match. Also not sure what newtonsoft will do with a class which has no parameterless constructor.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I think your answer is helpful, although I used Paste Special, Past JSON As Classes to obtain the same code. Although, it is part_parameters and probably fields vs. properties that are the issues that need to be identified.

Comment: Ok Jon. I will rename the properties. Would that help with the error though?

Comment: @sanchit : code example link https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-Csharp.aspx

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar okay, good, but I think it would also need to address what the issues are. Namely the naming part_parameters, use of fields vs. properties, removing the ctor, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a JSON attribute above your property, so that your properties are recognized when deserializing your object.

you will find an example just below

```
public class Parameters
{
    [JsonProperty("bar_diameter")]
    public float bar_diameter;
    [JsonProperty("core_height")]
    public float core_height;
    [JsonProperty("roughing_offset")]
    public float roughing_offset;

    public Parameters(float barD, float coreH, float roughingO)
    {
        bar_diameter = barD;
        core_height = coreH;
        roughing_offset = roughingO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your property is called 'parameters' but in your json it's 'part_parameters'.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Prasad Telkikar's answer as that fixed it right away

> Use json2csharp to get model for your json file, then deserialize your
>   json. You can use visual studio in build function to create class i.e.
>   Edit -> Paste special -> Paste JSON as Class
>
> Here is class

```
> public class PartParameters {
>     public double bar_diameter { get; set; }
>     public int core_height { get; set; }
>     public double roughing_offset { get; set; } }
> 
> public class RootObject {
>     public PartParameters part_parameters { get; set; } }
```

To deserialize, use below code

> PLMpartParameter part =
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

My final code looks like this, and its working!!

```
    public class PartParameters
    {
        public double bar_diameter { get; set; }
        public int core_height { get; set; }
        public double roughing_offset { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public PartParameters part_parameters { get; set; }
    }

    public static void LoadJson()
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader r = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\part_param.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            try
            {
                RootObject part = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

                _logger.Info(string.Format("list values : bardiameter: {0}, coreHeight: {1}, roughingOffset: {2}", 
                    part.part_parameters.bar_diameter,part.part_parameters.core_height, part.part_parameters.roughing_offset));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Info(string.Format("Read Json failed {0}", e.Message));
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You also need `[JsonProperty("part_parameters")]`

Comment: Yes! I am new to Json, so didn't know that i need to format my properties like this

Comment: This is saying "what I will call PartParameters is named in the JSON as part_parameters". You can add the same for bar_diameter etc., to retain C# naming.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code:

1. You need to have default constructors for the classes (this is due to how serializers work with types - they are not going to understand your class-specific paramaterised constructor).
2. Your fields need to be settable properties (Just add `{get;set;}` and you should be good to go).
3. I would suggest you decorate the `parameters` property with `[JsonProperty("part_parameters")]` to get the deserialization
   behaviour you're expecting.

Comment: I see. I tried the get; set;, but that didn't seem to do anything.

But as you mentioned in 3rd suggestion to decorate with [JsonProperty("part_parameters")], that did the trick